# how would one check a returned image-link with soapui testing?

Tags: image, testing, soapui

I'm creating some tests for an ad server, and I want to test the validity / correctness of the returned ads.

For this I would (from an assertion script) like to get the image link, and then retrieve the image and do some checks (width/height/format/does it exist, etc)

Has someone done this before?

I'm able to parse the link from the response, but am stuck on how to actually get the image.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you have the image attributes, you just need to download the image itself? I suspect you'll need to add a Groovy Script to retrieve embedded content.  Or, switch to Jmeter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's tricky. Assertion on certain strings recieved, if the xml is valid, or if the response is under certain threshold is no problem. But anything beyond this you have to script with either groovy or javascript. Although powerful probably, it's not the scripting language I'm easy with.

So I thought I might as well create unit test project in .Net using Nunit, and script the tests myself. Works perfect.